# How to get list of listener of spring controller?

Tags: java, spring

I want to retrieve a list of all handler methods in my Spring controllers. I could check all classes one by one, but that way requires too much time.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from version 3.1.SOMETHING, Spring offers [RequestMappingHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html) bean. That class has a method that returns a `Map` with the info you want: [getHandlerMethods()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.html#getHandlerMethods--). This map contains info about the `@RequestMapping` annotation in its keys, and about the method in the controller that matches the mapping in its values.

To use it, you simply autowire a `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` instance in any bean of your Spring MVC application:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Autowire
    RequestMappingHandlerMapping mappings;

    @PostConstruct // It could also be a @Bean getter, actually any method you want
    void init() {
        for (Entry<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> entry : this.mappings.getHandlerMethods().entrySet()) {
            // do something useful with the actual mapping
        }
    }
}
```

Not specific to your question, but `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` also offers uselful information about interceptors, content negotiator manager, url mapping configuration, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can harness the power of reflection to get your hands on a list of all @RequestMapping annotated methods within a certain package. Using [Google's reflections library](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) this could look as follows:

```
 Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");

 Set<Method> handlerMethods = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.class)
```